# Tag dropdown shows no suggestions

Tags: bug, tags, asking-questions, tag-autocomplete

When asking question and typing tags it sometimes "bugs", so I have to type the tag fully myself without option to autocomplete tag or to read tag description.

Happens just now. Typing tag, everything is fine:

[image]

---

Then suddenly this:

[image]

---

Refreshing page with <kbd>F5</kbd> helps:

[image]

---

Info: Windows 10, 64, Chrome.